# How to write a program that will print the first N numbers for a specific base?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I don't understand this question. What are we finding here?

Here's some additional detail given with it:
Print the first N numbers for a specific base:
The number 11 in base 10 =
1*(10^1)+1*(10^0)=11
Similarly the number 11 in base 7 =
1*(7^1)+1*(7^0)=8

For your understanding, I found this solution online, but I am not able to understand it.

```
{int trm, bs, r, q, i, num;
 cout << " Input the number of term: ";
    cin >> trm;
    cout << " Input the base: ";
    cin >> bs;
    cout << " The numbers in base " << bs << " are: " << endl;
    for (i = 1; i <= trm; i++) 
    {
        r = i % bs;
        q = i / bs;
        num = q * 10 + r;
        cout << num << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Input the number of term: 15
Input the base: 7
The numbers in base 7 are:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 20
```

I am new to coding. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/base-numbers-.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r = i % bs;`finds remainder (which can make sure it is within 0 to 6);
`q = i / bs;` finds how many "7" needs for tenth value.
 `num = q * 10 + r;` is to calculate the value in base 7 .
this function maybe work until term 489th.
if you want to do extra, you may check the ,

```
if(i > 489)
{
    y = i / (bs*bs);
    num = y*100 + q*10 + r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{int trm, bs, r, q, i, num;
```

This declares the variables.

```
 cout << " Input the number of term: ";
    cin >> trm;
    cout << " Input the base: ";
    cin >> bs;
    cout << " The numbers in base " << bs << " are: " << endl;
```

This assigns value to the variables while also couting lines.

```
    for (i = 1; i <= trm; i++)
```

This means, for a number of time equal to the number of terms requested, repeat whats in the curly brackets({})

```
    {
        r = i % bs;
        q = i / bs;
        num = q * 10 + r;
        cout << num << "  ";
    }
```

This converts the number i (from 1, increases by 1 each loop) into the new number in the new base, then couts the number. Note how it takes the remainder of the number divided by the base and the number divided by the base with remainder removed, then combines them to form the new number.

```
    cout << endl;
}
```

And this just creates a new line at the end of the code. Hope this helps